# App not going to silent mode, possible audio manager bug?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Here I'm trying to change my phone to silent mode as I reach a particular location.

This is for a college project, In this I'm trying to put the device to silent mode as soon as in enter in to college premises.

This is my MainActivity file.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.media.AudioManager;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    public double lattitude,longitude;

    public AudioManager am;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_location);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_location);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        if(lattitude == 21.92000007629394 || longitude == 82.77999877929686){
           am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

        }
        else if(lattitude == 18.587765599999997 || longitude == 73.7407158){
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            getLocation();


        }
    }

    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager. PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                double latti = location.getLatitude();
                double longi = location.getLongitude();
                lattitude = latti;
                longitude = longi;

                textView.setText("Your current location is"+ "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                        + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);




            } else  if (location1 != null) {
                double latti = location1.getLatitude();
                double longi = location1.getLongitude();
                lattitude = latti;
                longitude = longi;

                textView.setText("Your current location is"+ "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                        + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);




            } else  if (location2 != null) {
                double latti = location2.getLatitude();
                double longi = location2.getLongitude();
                lattitude = latti;
                longitude = longi;

                textView.setText("Your current location is"+ "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                        + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);



            }else{

                Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to Trace your location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }

    protected void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Please Turn ON your GPS Connection")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

I tried placing the code to change phone to silent mode in different places like after the printing of the latitude and longitude and also before call to getLocation(), but either of those crashes the app.

And this is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.idks.locationsilent">



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: any log report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recent API's we need to give access to application's for changing phone profiles.

I just needed to add this fragment.

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings
                            .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
```